# Object attribute from Array disappears when mapping through the array (REACT)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, array.prototype.map

I am fetching all 'years' from a database, and storing it in an empty array

[getting all years](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Hm6.png)

For each year, I am fetching all its respective 'months' and adding the returned object (12 of them since it 12 months)

[getting all months](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAxnO.png)

When I console out the main array 'periods', and when I map through it and console out each period will give me this.

[console.log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e0oM.png)

As you can see, the months attribute does not show in 'periods' array and I do not know why.

I am expecting to be able to access the months array within the periods array but to no avail even though its clearly there.

Comment: Please [do not post a link to a painting of the code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572)! You can [edit] your question to include the code as [formatted text](/help/formatting).

Comment: Where are you console logging `period`? None of the screenshots you provided have `console.log(period)` Also in your 'getting all months' you're not using the `period` data anywhere, which is the data that contains the months